# how to create multi colored button in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, frontend

i would like to create a button below button

[image: multi color button]

how can i create this type of button basically my want to create a button that botton stating color is like colors.red[100] and and buttons ending point is like color.red[900] between starting and ending point my button is like growing up color.

for eg(starting color red[100] and red[101] then red[102] and so on) like create lighter to dark color in a single button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gradient` and `boxShadow`

```
Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.red[100],
                Colors.red[900],
              ]
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                color: Colors.red[100],
                blurRadius: 16.0,
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                color: Colors.red[200],
                blurRadius: 16.0,
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                color: Colors.red[300],
                blurRadius: 16.0,
              ),
            ]
          ),
          child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 18.0))
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gradient` inside `Container` widget

Here is the full code:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class ClassName extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
  
     //You can add Appbar like this
     appBar: AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       centerTitle: true,
       title: Text('This is appbar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),),
     ),

     body: SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
         child: Column(
           children: [

             //You can add other Widgets here

             Container(
               child: GestureDetector(
                 onTap: (){
                   //add functions of this button here
                 },
                 child: Container(
                   height: 50.0,
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     gradient: LinearGradient(
                       begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       end: Alignment.centerRight,
                       colors: [Colors.red[100], Colors.red[900]],
                     ),
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                   ),
                   child: Center(
                     child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),),
                   ),
                 ),
               )
             ),

             //You can add other Widgets here
           
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
```

**Here is the Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

I think this is what you are asking for.

And do let me know if need any other help.

Comment: The `onTap` function is only triggered when there is a tap on the `Login text` and not the `Container` itself. You can improve by wrapping the whole `Container` in any gesture detection widget @Hardik Kumar

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that.

Comment: Check the code now. I've added full code with a screenshot also. If you want to add shadow, just tell me, i'll do it. Let me know if want any other help.

Answer (score 0):

To make your `Button` have variety of `Colors`, you can use a `Container` widget and customise the `gradient` property based on your preference.

I have added a demo code below to help you with what you are requesting for:

```
           // use a container widget
            Container(
              // customize the height property
              height: 50,
              // customize the width property
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // spice up the button with a radius
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    // gradient starts from left
                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    // gradient ends at right
                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                    // set all your colors
                    colors: [
                      Colors.red[100],
                      Colors.red[200],
                      Colors.red[300],
                      Colors.red[400],
                      Colors.red[500],
                      Colors.red[600],
                      Colors.red[700],
                      Colors.red[800],
                      Colors.red[900],
                    ]),
              ),
              // the button text
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: You just need to add the end colors in the `gradient` and it will do the same. You are just increasing the size of your code, nothing else.

Comment: Adding two sets of colors will produce a different output @HardikKumar. Try the code, I provided the link: https://codepen.io/timilehinjegede/pen/WNryOVr

Comment: If you use `stops` property of `LinearGradient`, then only it will differ. I tried it, that's why i am saying .

Comment: This deviates from the original question, the question asks how to set gradients from Light([100])  shade of a color to the darkest shade @HardikKumar

Comment: I recommend you to try my code and you'll get my point.

Comment: it does not work its showing a runtime error like this (MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a mediaquery.NO media query ancestor from the context that was passed to media query.of(). do not have a widgetsApp or widget...)) @HardikKumar

Comment: @HardikKumar hey brother can you provide me just complete code of that because i am new in flutter technology and may be this error cause some depandies

Comment: @TimilehinJegede pls you also help me

Comment: See full code here @Rohanjangid https://gist.github.com/timilehinjegede/8dbfad45885799bc577cc0ac1281d5e0